# Funnel all the WiFi hotspot traffic through Tor

Tags: linux, tor

I'm using my Fedora 16 machine as a WiFi hotspot, I want to funnel all my network traffic (from the laptop and all the other devices) through [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/), is this possible? Or are there any other solutions to achieve this goal?

Comment: (1) Install Tor, (2) Install local proxy using tor (3) modify your iptables to route all traffic through the proxy (4) profit. You might like this Tutorial: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy